Using an Excel Macro to populate a Word Template?
I have a long list of customer data that I am trying to use to fill out a template in Word. This includes customer name, preferences, location, etc- for 200 rows of customers. I am getting Compile Error: User-defined type not defined.
Can someone please help me, I'm very new to this so not sure what I should be looking for or how to fix it. I did this based off a youtube video.
Thank you in advance for any help and guidance!
Sub ReplaceText()
    Dim wApp As Word.Application
    Dim wdoc As Word.Document   
    Dim custN, path As String
    Dim r As Long
    r = 2
    Do While Sheet1.Cells(r, 1) (not equal to) ""
    Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wApp.Visible = True
    Set wdoc = wApp.Documents.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\msira\Desktop\Owner Summit\Owner Summit Profiles Template MS1.dotm", ReadOnly:=True)
    With wdoc
        .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "||WAVE||"
        .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
        .Application.Selection = Sheet1.Cells(r, 1).Value    
        .Application.Selection.EndOf
        .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "||FIRST NAME||"
        .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
        .Application.Selection = Sheet1.Cells(r, 2).Value
        .Application.Selection.EndOf
    
        .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "||LAST NAME||"
        .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
        .Application.Selection = Sheet1.Cells(r, 3).Value
        .Application.Selection.EndOf
    
        .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "||PHONE||"
        .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
        .Application.Selection = Sheet1.Cells(r, 4).Value
        .Application.Selection.EndOf
    
        .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "||EMAIL||"
        .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
        .Application.Selection = Sheet1.Cells(r, 5).Value
        .Application.Selection.EndOf
    
        .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "||LOCATION||"
        .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
        .Application.Selection = Sheet1.Cells(r, 6).Value
        .Application.Selection.EndOf
    
        .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "||STORES||"
        .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
        .Application.Selection = Sheet1.Cells(r, 7).Value
        .Application.Selection.EndOf
    
        .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "||DRINK||"
        .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
        .Application.Selection = Sheet1.Cells(r, 8).Value
        .Application.Selection.EndOf
    
        .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "||FOOD||"
        .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
        .Application.Selection = Sheet1.Cells(r, 9).Value
        .Application.Selection.EndOf
    
        .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "||MUSIC||"
        .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
        .Application.Selection = Sheet1.Cells(r, 10).Value
        .Application.Selection.EndOf
    
        .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "||EDUCATION||"
        .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
        .Application.Selection = Sheet1.Cells(r, 11).Value
        .Application.Selection.EndOf
    
        .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "||BACKGROUND||"
        .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
        .Application.Selection = Sheet1.Cells(r, 12).Value
        .Application.Selection.EndOf
    
        .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "||PERSONAL||"
        .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
        .Application.Selection = Sheet1.Cells(r, 13).Value
        .Application.Selection.EndOf
    
        custN = Sheet1.Cells(r, 1).Value path = "C:\Users\msira\Desktop\Owner Summit\Owners Summit Profiles"
        .SaveAs2 Filename:=path & custN, _ FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddtoRecentFiles:=False
    End With
    r = r + 1
    Loop
End Sub


You need to add a reference to the WORD object library e.g. as per this video.

reference video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6zEUJfZcA9c

Note also that (not equal to) is not valid syntax, it should just be <>

I would suggest Googling "mail merge Microsoft Word"

Word bookmark is an option for you. https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/WorkWithBookmarks.htm . It's easier to locate bookmark than a space-holder text.
